# script service for parsing json data fetched from the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Does the script service means creating a webservice in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - except you should indicate that web service will be used from java script by tagging the class with [ScriptService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute (this enables JSON serialization on the end point).